# Integral transform acting on kernel with both arguments identified

Tags: functional-analysis, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

This is purely a question sprung out of curiosity. If I have some $K(x,y)\in L^2(\mathbb{C}^2)$ and define the corresponding integral operator on $L^2(\mathbb{C})$

$$
L_K(f)=\int f(y)K(x,y)dy
$$

is there anything interesting that happens when we act this operator on its own kernel with both arguments identified? ie, if I define $K(x):=K(x,x)$, is there anything interesting about the action of $L_{K(x,y)}$ on $K(x)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $K$ is in $L^2({\mathbb C})$ then $K$ is actually not a function, but rather an equivalence class of square integrable functions modulo equality
a.e.  Since the diagonal
$$
  \Delta :=\{(x,x): x\in {\mathbb C}\}
  $$
has measure zero, you  may change the values of $K$ randomly on $\Delta $,  without changing the class of $K$  and, most
importantly,  without changing the integral operator.

I'd therefore say that your question is not a well posed question, as $K(x,x)$ can be anything you want.

Comment: Yes this is true, although I guess I meant K(x) as the equivalence class of functions $f(x)$ such that $f(x)=K(x,x)$ almost everywhere.

Comment: I insist, $K(x,x)$ has no meaning whatsoever.  This is like asking "do you like the player of such and such soccer team?"  You may be thinking of one player while I am thinking of another, so my answer will be meaningless to you.

Comment: yes, my mistake